# Get the value from list

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

I create the list like

```
var list = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
list.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("1", "abc"));
list.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("2", "def"));
list.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("3", "ghi"));
```

How to select the value from this list.
Which means I need to pass 1 to the list and need to take the equal value "abc".How to do this? input is 1,output is abc.

Comment: var res = list.Single(x => x.Key == "1").Value

Answer (score 6):

It sounds like you just want:

```
var value = list.First(x => x.Key == input).Value;
```

That's if you're sure the key will be present. It's slightly trickier otherwise, partly because `KeyValuePair` is a struct. You'd probably want:

```
var pair = list.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == input);
if (pair.Key != null)
{
    // Yes, we found it - use pair.Value
}
```

Any reason you're not just using a `Dictionary<string, string>` though? That's the more natural representation of a key/value pair collection:

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    { "1", "abc" },
    { "2", "def" },
    { "3", "ghi" }
};
```

Then:

```
var value = dictionary[input];
```

Again, assuming you know the key will be present. Otherwise:

```
string value;
if (dictionary.TryGetValue(input, out value))
{
    // Key was present, the value is now stored in the value variable
}
else
{
    // Key was not present
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why are you not using a Dictionary? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx

It seems to me this would solve your problem, and it's much easier to use.